# Correct Ruby indentation for a bunch of files in one go

Tags: ruby, formatting, indentation

I have a lot of ruby files with incorrect indentation.

How can I fix it automatically (with help of some tool) other than manually?

Example:

```
feature 'HAPPY/3_step_minimal_foundation_no_prefill_HAPPY' do
    visit('http://staging.everquote/url_reset') # should be 2 spaces not 4
    visit('http://staging.everquote/url_3_step_minimal_foundation')
    with_ajax_wait do
      expect(css_zip_code).to be_visible # should be 4 spaces not 6
  end
```

Comment: Probably a good text editor has a function to do that. You can probably write a script to open the files one by one with that script and apply such function then save.

Comment: Yeah in vim I can do `:1`  `v`  `shift-g` and then `=` but it is a manual operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out rubocop, which I was using already to check the format and which is currently maintained (as of September 2015) has a -a option to actually fix the files.  Sweet!

https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop

Answer (score 1):

This [ruby beautifier](https://github.com/erniebrodeur/ruby-beautify) contains logic to re-indent your code.

You could either run the script as-is or extract those parts.

Comment: Thanks, how exactly to use?  I tried `$ ruby rbeautify.rb rspec_conversions/3sm_happy_rspec.rb` which gave an error and then I spent 15 minutes trying combinations of requiring and including the module to no avail.  I am on ruby 2.2.1

Comment: I also tried `cat rspec_conversions/3sm_happy_rspec.rb | ruby rbeautify.rb` and got `rbeautify.rb:118: warning: character class has duplicated range: /.*=\s*<<-?\s*([_|\w]+).*/
usage: Ruby filenames or "-" for stdin.`

Comment: Apologies, that was the old version. You probably want https://github.com/erniebrodeur/ruby-beautify.